# How do you get the tid from a taxonomy term page?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I've got a component on a taxonomy term page and need to use the TID in it's preprocess function.

How do I actually get the tid to save as a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`menu_get_object()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7.x):

```
$term = menu_get_object('taxonomy_term', 2);
if ($term) {
  $tid = $term->tid;
}
```